# Hidden edit button in GridView using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, edit

I have entered this condition in my dataset

1. when the value of message is equal to `"1"` it is not possible to continue working on this webpage...
2. when the value of message is equal to `"0"` it's possible to continue but it's not possible to edit the `gridview` data...

My code below

```
if (message == 1)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('test msg 1');window.location='Default.aspx';", true);
    return null;
}
else if (message == 0)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('test msg 2');", true);
    btrila.Visible = false;
    btnreset.Visible = true;
    return dsProducts;
}
else
{
    return dsProducts;
}
```

when the value of message is equal to `"0"` I need hidden or disable the button below for `edit` the `gridview` data

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnedit" runat="server"
        CommandName="Edit"
        ImageUrl="/aspnet/img/edit_icon.gif"
        ToolTip="Edit" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

I have tried this solution in `RowDataBound` without success because the `"btnedit"` is always hidden...

Any help would greatly appreciate... Thank you.

```
protected void gvProducts_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
        {
            if (btnreset.Visible == true)
            {
                gvProducts.Columns[2].Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                gvProducts.Columns[2].Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when the value of message is equal to "0" I need hidden or disable the
> button below for edit the gridview data

on the DataBound function you need to loop the cells and locate your control - here is how

```
protected void onRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // loop all data rows
        foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            // check all cells in one row
            foreach (Control control in cell.Controls)
            {
                // go to find this button
                Button button = control as Button;
                if (button != null && button.CommandName == "Edit")                        
                      button.Enable = false; // or true depend on your contitions.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I have tried your suggestion the "btnedit" is always visible...

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis Check your code, this is the way. You can also try just to add some css on the button.